# Python3: Is a write to UDP socket as file object even possible?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, makefile, udp

In Python3 I created a socket with `s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)` in order to send UDP to a certain destination in the network. Now the classical way would be to `s.sendto(my_data, (ip, port))`. But I would like to handle the socket as an io file object. Therefore I created one by `f = s.makefile(mode='wb')`. Now I can use `f.write(my_data)` to send data. **But wait** ... I never had to specify IP and port. Needless to say, the data does not arrive at the destination. With TCP there is no problem because with `s.connect((ip, port))` I can specify ip and port before I create a file object.

Is it possible, and if yes how, to send UDP with a socket as file object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okey...as I was writing the question it occurred to me that I could try calling `s.connect((ip, port))` on the UDP socket although there is no connection to establish. Voilà it works. Maybe this helps somebody.